# How to professionally address the receiver in the email to the company

Tags: job-search, recruitment, email

I apologize if the title is confusing. I recently graduated from college and am now looking for jobs. So I have been job hunting and looking into different job positions. Sometimes, I have some questions about the position and want to send an email to clarify some confusions. Now some companies do provide such email, for example  XXXXXXXXjobacquisition@company.com. Since I am not sure who will be receiving the email(HR, hiring manager etc). How would I address the receiver in such email?

```
Dear team?
Dear <company name>?
```

I am also a foreign student, so any detailed explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to professionally address an unknown recipient is with:

> To whom it may concern

Of course, you should always attempt to determine the name of the person receiving the email.  That way, you can send a more personalized email.

Comment: How would you address me, knowing only my name?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Dear or Hello Patricia Shanahan

Comment: This is probably a seperate question worthy, but given only their general recruiting email, how do I find out the name of the person receiving it?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I am not a native English speaker as well.

I always use "Dear Sir/Miss" in these situations. Although there is a lot to do nowadays about people not falling in either of those two categories, I still think it is a safe choice in more than 99 percent of the cases.

Comment: You should probably change 'miss' to 'madam' here, since 'miss' carries the extra meaning of *unmarried* woman whereas madam is just a formal wat to refer to a woman.